# How can I define a parameterless constructor in an Oracle PL/SQL type?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How can I define a parameterless constructor in an Oracle PL/SQL type? I've tried this:

```
create or replace type FooBar as object
(
    constructor function FooBar() return self as result
);

...

foo_bar := FooBar();
```

But the empty parameter list in the type declaration raises PLS-00103.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you don't need brackets after the name of the parameterless function
and you need a definition for the body ot the constructor:

```
create or replace type FooBar as object
(
    bar NUMBER(1,0)
    ,constructor function FooBar return self as result
);
/


create or replace type body FooBar is

    constructor function FooBar return self as result
    IS
    BEGIN
    RETURN;
    END;
end;
/


    declare 
     foo foobar;
    begin
      foo := foobar();
    end;
   /
```

Comment: You'll also need to define a parameterless constructor in any subclasses.